# ElasticSearch: Multi-level nested query "AND" syntax

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an index similar to the example index shown in the elasticsearch doc multi-level nested query example:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#multi-level-nested-query-ex

Given these example docs:

```
{
  "driver" : {
        "last_name" : "McQueen",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
}

{
  "driver" : {
        "last_name" : "Hudson",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Mifune",
                "model" : "Mach Five"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to be able to find documents where the driver.vehicle.make matches two values, i.e. the driver who has both vehicle makes "Powell Motors" and "Miller-meteor" should match McQueen but not Hudson.
I've tried a query similar to the doc example's make and model query, but it returns 0 docs:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "driver",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "driver.vehicle",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "driver.vehicle.make": "Powell Motors" } },
                { "match": { "driver.vehicle.make": "Miller-Meteor" } }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the "must" to a "should" returns both docs. I can't seem to find a query that will query the vehicle array for multiple value matches in the same doc.

Answer (score 0):

The above query returns 0 documents, as there is no single document (inside `driver.vehicle`) in your example that has `driver.vehicle.make` value as "Powell Motors" and "Miller-meteor".

**Note:** Here single documents refer to each individual documents (or objects) inside `driver.vehicle`.

Therefore, when you are changing the `must` clause to `should` clause it returns those documents (in this case both the doc), that have `driver.vehicle.make` value as `"Powell Motors" OR "Miller-meteor"`. `must` works as logical AND operator, and `should` works as logical OR operator.

According to your requirement, I believe you want those documents where **driver who has vehicle makes "Powell Motors" OR "Miller-meteor" should match McQueen but not Hudson**.

In this case, you need to combine a nested query with a normal query, which can be done using a bool query.

Your modified query will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "driver",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "driver.last_name": "McQueen"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "driver.vehicle",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "driver.vehicle.make": "Powell Motors"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "driver.vehicle.make": "Miller-Meteor"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the search result will be

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "soidx1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 3.105637,
        "_source" : {
          "driver" : {
            "last_name" : "McQueen",
            "vehicle" : [
              {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
              },
              {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @MWuerstl please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe, my question wasn't clear, but I don't know that I want driver McQueen when I run the query. I want any driver who has at least 2 vehicles, one must be make "Powell Motors" and one must be "Miller-Meteor". In the example data McQueen should be the only driver result of the query I'm trying to build. But the query shouldn't be limited by the driver's name as in a larger data set, there may be other drivers with those same two vehicle makes.